# AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: blogs.wrapper but I am not overwriting anything?

Tags: python

So, while trying to code something, I saw this error, but I am not actually overwriting anything, at least from what I know. Can anyone help? Here is the full code
I don't know what really happened here, and I really need help quickly, please.
My friend also reviewed it and said he doesn't know what that means either, so I really wanted to fix it, I am writing this because I have to also put more text, but please help if you can, thank you!

````
import jsonify
from flask_jwt_extended import jwt_required

from api import db

blogs= Blueprint('blogs',__name__)

@blogs.route("/add_blog", methods=["POST"])
@jwt_required
def create_blog():
    data = request.get_json()
 
    new_blog=Blog(title=data["title"],content=data["content"],feature_image=data["feature_image"])
 
    for tag in data["tags"]:
        present_tag=Tag.query.filter_by(name=tag).first()
        if(present_tag):
            present_tag.blogs_associated.append(new_blog)
        else:
            new_tag=Tag(name=tag)
            new_tag.blogs_associated.append(new_blog)
            db.session.add(new_tag)
            
 
    db.session.add(new_blog)
    db.session.commit()
 
    blog_id = getattr(new_blog, "id")
    return jsonify({"id": blog_id})


@blogs.route('/blogs',methods=["GET"])
def get_all_blogs():
    blogs= Blog.query.all()
    serialized_data = []
    for blog in blogs:
        serialized_data.append(blog.serialize)
 
    return jsonify({"all_blogs": serialized_data})
    
@blogs.route('/blog/<int:id>',methods=["GET"])
def get_single_blog(id):
    blog = Blog.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
    serialized_blog = blog.serialize
    serialized_blog["tags"] = []
 
    for tag in blog.tags:
        serialized_blog["tags"].append(tag.serialize)
 
    return jsonify({"single_blog": serialized_blog})

@blogs.route('/update_blog/<int:id>', methods=["PUT"])
@jwt_required
def update_blog(id):
    data = request.get_json()
    blog=Blog.query.filter_by(id=id).first_or_404()
 
    blog.title = data["title"]
    blog.content=data["content"]
    blog.feature_image=data["feature_image"]
 
    updated_blog = blog.serialize
 
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({"blog_id": blog.id})

@blogs.route('/delete_blog/<int:id>', methods=["DELETE"])
@jwt_required
def delete_blog(id):
    blog = Blog.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
    db.session.delete(blog)
    db.session.commit()
 
    return jsonify("Blog was deleted"),20```
````

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: I see you use `Blueprint` so maybe in other file you run code which use the same names